# Registers and Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

If we use all registers in Assembly language then what will my CPU use? I mean are  registers divided in such a way that CPU can use independently and also We can use it independently

Comment: What? Registers can be used independently, yes. It would be pointless if they'd share their memory.

Comment: Are you thinking of *inline* assembly in C or something, and wondering what's left for the *compiler* to use?  The compiler-generated and hand-written code both use registers and run on the CPU, just like if you'd written the whole function by hand.  Some compilers will stop you from declaring clobbers or or using *all* the registers as input/output operands.

Comment: CPU has registers, "you" have no registers. If you use some registers in assembly, you are using CPU's registers. If you use all of them, you use all of them. There's nothing "independent" about it, registers in CPU are like "super-globals", having only single instance at particular time (even when modern OS is switching between different tasks, it has to use special sequence of instructions to save current state of registers for old thread/process and load the previous state of registers for the thread/process into which it is going to switch, otherwise multitasking would be not possible).

Answer (score 1):

Registers store temporary values for calculations. All other data is stored in external memory. External memory could be cached in different ways, but it is always slower than registers.